# TypeScript: How to call a function in the parent class?

Tags: typescript

Here in nodes.tsx I'm importing InputHandler

```
import { InputHandler } from './inputHandler';

class Nodes {
  canvasWidth: number;
  canvasHeight: number;

  constructor(width: number, height: number) {
    this.canvasWidth = width;
    this.canvasHeight = height;
    new InputHandler(this);
//         ^ error
  }
  clicked() {
    console.log('clicked');
  }
}

export { Nodes };
```

I get the error `unused expression, expected an assignment or function call (no-unused-expression)tslint(1)`

```
class InputHandler {
    constructor(nodes: any) {
//                      ^ error, im passing in `this` from the parent
        document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            nodes.clicked();
        });
    }
}

export { InputHandler };
```

and inside input handler, I'm trying to call `clicked()` in the parent. I also get the error 
`Type declaration of 'any' loses type-safety. Consider replacing it with a more precise type. (no-any)tslint(1)`

When I click the canvas or the page the clicked() function doesn't get called.

I get the feeling the entire pattern is wrong somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create an interface for `Nodes`, which will be then implemented by the class, and export it.

```
export interface INodes {
    clicked(): void
}
```

Then inside of `InputHandler` import `INodes`, and use it as the type in the constructor:

```
class InputHandler {
    constructor(nodes: INodes) {
        document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            nodes.clicked();
        });
    }
}
```

And import `INodes` and add `implements INodes` to your `Nodes` class, like this:

```
class Nodes implements INodes {
    canvasWidth: number;
    canvasHeight: number;

    constructor(width: number, height: number) {
      this.canvasWidth = width;
      this.canvasHeight = height;
      const handler = new InputHandler(this);
    }

    clicked() {
      console.log('clicked');
    }
}
```

This will resolve your second problem. For the first problem, you need to store the result of your `new InputHandler` in a variable, like I've done above.

Comment: I get the error `Cannot re-export a type when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided.ts(1205)` is this something I can turn of safely? I guess create react app has set it by default.

Comment: You can use the `export interface` syntax instead to avoid the issue. Default `tsconfig.json` in CRA is usually something you should follow if you want to adhere to TS's best practices.

Comment: it all feels good I just get one error `'handler' is assigned a value but never used  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars` and when I click the page clicked() doesn't get called

Comment: I tslint ignored the error and fixed another issue and now it works

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you use contructors:

```
const handler = new InputHandler(this);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor

Comment: thank you, I assigned it to a variable as you suggested and clicked still doesn't get called